# Swift return empty string extension function when string 0 or 0.0

Tags: swift, string, function

I have simple app using `coredata` in **Swift4** when I want to get some text labels shows values 0.0 , or 0 , or 0.00 I want to clear all of them.

I want to add string extension to clear . **But my codes doesn't work,**
My codes under below

```
 extension String {
        var doempty: String {
            if (self.doempty == "0.00" || self.doempty == "0.0" || self.doempty = "0"){
                return ""
            }else{
                return doempty
            }
        }
    }
```

Example;

```
selfmylabel.text = selfmylabel.text.doempty
```

Comment: Wow, so recursive code.

Comment: Why not simply `return Double(self) == 0.0 ? "" : self`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are making an extension of `String` so you need to use `self` in your code , so you can do something like this:

```
extension String {
    var doempty: String {
        if (self == "0.00" || self == "0.0" || self == "0"){
            return ""
        }else{
            return self
        }
    }
}
```